# Opening file issue

Tags: c, file

I have a problem with my code and I hope you can help. I won't post all the code because it's a little long, but I will focus on the troublesome part. 
The program is about algebraic operation with arrays. The read_array2 reads the first nxn real numbers from a file and place them in a global array. The problem is that I always get the same message "I cannot open this file". I even added a printf() to test if the name is properly stored in fname and I found that it is. And yes, I have verified that the files I use exist and I type their names correctly. 
I don't know if it is important, but the files have 10000 real numbers separated by a single space.
I know it is difficult to tell without all the code available, but do you see something out of place that could cause this issue?

```
int read_array2(double table[N_MAX][N_MAX], int n){
int i, j;
FILE *infile;
char fname[25];

printf("\nFile Name: ");
scanf("%s",&fname);

if ((infile = fopen(fname,"r")) == NULL){
    printf("\nI cannot open this file.\n");
    return 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
    fscanf(infile, "%lf ", &table[i][j]);
}

fclose(infile);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you in the right directory? Or did you type the full path? If so, is 25 characters enough for that? Also, could it be that another program has locked the file? Maybe an issue with permissions? Which platform are you on?

Comment: Just tested the code myself to make sure and the first part works (not testing after fopen) assuming the file is in the same directory and the file name is small.

Comment: I am an idiot. I saved the program file in a different directory and didn't copy the files in the same folder. And since the .c file existed in both folders I thought I had opened the right one. Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to type in the extension of the file as well? For example: to open a text file called "MyFile" you need to enter "MyFile.txt" Also if it's not in the same directory of your program, you will need to include the full path as well. Note: The file names are case sensitive and when typing in a path you need to escape the escapes "\\" or use '/' i.e. C:\\Users\\MyFile.txt or C:/Users/MyFile.txt

Comment: The problem was that I had not copied the files in the same folder after I saved the program in a second directory. Thanks for the reply.